# Need derailleur hanger

Tags: derailleur

I have what I believe is a 1994 Cannondale.  I need a derailleur hanger and I’m tired of thinking I’m ordering the right one and it’s not.  Can somebody please tell me how to find out what my bike is? I have the serial number and all that but I’m a bit confused on how to figure it out...

Comment: Add a clear, well lit, hight resolution picture of the bike taken from the drive side to the question.

Comment: There is an outfit out there that I've used once and others have also found it useful.  You send them the info you have, plus a picture, and they guarantee a fit.  Unfortunately I can't remember the name of the outfit, but maybe someone else can.

Comment: Why not ask Cannondale directly?

Comment: Any Cannondale dealer can provide hangers. And most LBS have comparison charts or catalogues for ordering hangers.

Comment: @DanielRHicks We recently had a bunch of posts from a guy at Elanus Parts -- maybe it was them? (I guess those posts got deleted as too spammy.)

Comment: Here is the outfit I was speaking of: http://wheelsmfg.com/

Comment: Do you have the old hanger still?  Even in pieces it can be reassembled to show what the replacement should look like.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a link to the to a website that discusses how to determine from the serial number what year your Cannondale was made. 
http://vintagecannondale.com/info/serial_numbers/
Then you can  cross reference that year's catalog, determine the model you have and then be able to get a list of parts/part numbers. The relevant letters and numbers should be stamped on the underside of the bottom bracket shell. Between 1993 & 1999, a two letter code stamped in one corner of the underside of the BB shell represents the year and month of manufacture. The letter F happens to represent 1994. See website. 
Once you've determined the year made, a Google search (example: "1994 Cannondale catalog")  will turn up hits that link to a PDF file of that years catalog. Utilizing color scheme and component clues, you then locate the correct model.  With this knowledge you can call up the correct part and part numbers. This may sound convoluted but in just a couple minutes, I had a catalog downloaded and was ready to find a match. Bear in mind that the bike may be manufactured in the year prior to it's model year (the first 2019 bikes were being produced as early as last summer). So one may have to look at, 4say, a 1995 catalog for the correct bike despite sporting a "born on" date of 1994.
Here's another helpful link on the subject:
https://derailleurhangerstore.co.uk/pages/how-to-identify-your-derailleur-hanger
Good luck!